# How to set position of label always in the middle of vertical align of input

Tags: html, css

I have a label before input with float: right. How to set position of label always in the middle of vertical align of input?
My css is below:

```
label {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  float: right;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

And This is my html:

```
<div id='parent'>
  <label id='caption'>Name</label>
  <input type='text'/>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `float` for layout purposes. `float` has other use cases.

You can use `flex` on parent together with `aling-items: center`

See below

```css
label {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: right;

}

input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80%;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <label id='caption'>Name</label>
  <input type='text' />
</div>
```